# Primary key composed with JPA in Java

Tags: java, jpa, primary-key

Is there a solution to declare a primary key composed of two fields with JPA in Java ?

Exemple :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Id
private String identity;
```

The primary key is (id, identity).

Comment: check out this page http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id under Composite Primary Key

Comment: @kism3t i don't undestand the exemple. Or, it is enough just to add `@IdClass` to may Entity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a class with the `@IdClass` annotation, which will be known as the composed key.

For example:

```
@Table('myTable')
@IdClass(ComposedKey.class)
public class myEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private String identity;

    private String otherFields;

}

public class ComposedKey implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String identity;

    //Getter / Setter

}
```

Then, your key will be a `ComposedKey`.

Comment: In `ComposedKey` class, i declared just a primary key ? And in my Entity, can i declared my other fields ?

Comment: The `ComposedKey` class is just used to handle a composed primary key. After that, you can declare what you want in your Entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways of accomplishing this. It is easy to find this answer in the www.

Take a look at this: http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id#Composite_Primary_Key_

Greets.

[UPDATE]

I prefer the use of embedded PK:

```
@Embeddable
public class ClassPK implements Serializable {
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 145)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 145)
    private String idOne;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer idTwo;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 145)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 145)
    private String idThree;
```

And then in the Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "", schema = "")
public class Entity implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected ClassPK classPK ;

    @Column(name = "date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    @Column(name = "realTime", precision = 22)
    private Double realTime;
    @Size(max = 150)
    @Column(name = "cnc", length = 150)
    private String cnc;
```

As you can see in the Id class you can have as many fields as you want (in my case I have a composite PK of 3 fields).

And in the entity you define all the other columns.

Comment: I saw this solution but i don't understand it . If into my class i have a primary key composed of two fields and i have some other columns like that for exemple ?
`@Entity @IdClass(ProjectId.class)
public class Project {
    @Id int departmentId;
    @Id long projectId;
    @column(name="first_name")
}`

Comment: You can have as many fields as you want, along with your composite PK.
The annotation @IdClass just points your entity that the PK is declared in class ProjectId. But in your entity, you can define the other columns the usual way.
But I prefer to use embedded id class.